# Derandomizing AP existence in $A\subseteq \{1,\ldots,N\}$ for $\delta(A) \geq 1/k$

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

In the answer to the mathoverflow question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/238890/probability-of-no-k-1s-in-arithmetic-progression-in-binary-sequence-of-length/239153#239153), it was established that if we let $p$ be the probability of including point $v$ in $A\subseteq \{1,\ldots,N\}$ and this is done independently for all points $v\in \{1,\ldots,N\}$ then the length of the longest arithmetic progression (AP) in the set $A$ converges to 
$$
2(\ln (1/p))^{-1}{\ln N}
$$
in a reasonably strong sense, as established in the paper [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0707.3888).

Let us fix $k$ and let $N$ grow. Is it possible to prove directly a lower bound to the longest arithmetic progression in a set $A$ of density $\delta\geq 1/k$.

For concreteness take $\delta\geq 1/3,$ say. I would like to also have $\delta<1/2.$ I know about Szemeredi's Theorem, but my $\delta$ is reasonably close to $1/2$ so I am hoping something stronger can be stated.

If it helps, I'll accept not just an AP but a modular AP (with wraparound) whereby it would be more natural to take $\{0,\ldots,N-1\}$ and consider an AP of length $\ell$ to be $\{a+kd~(mod~N):0\leq k\leq \ell-1\}.$

Comment: is this supposed to be an answer, not a question?

Comment: I am editing it now, didn't know how to save and had to switch devices, sorry!

Comment: @WillSawin do you have any comments on the question?